# Two-way databinding with observable instance fields on the View?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

When using Android two-way databinding, do I have to use static `BindingAdapter`s on the `View` or is it somehow possible to simply use observable instance fields? In the documentation I always see observable fields only on the `ViewModel`s, not on the `View`. I tried implementing observable fields on my `View` with

```
var myValue: String = ""
@Bindable get(): String {
    return field
}
set(value: String) {
    field=value
    setText(value)
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myValue) // my View implements the Observable interface
}
```

but when I compile this (with `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` to get the details), it fails with

```
ERROR: Cannot find a getter for <com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView app:myValue> 
that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'

If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly
and that the parameter type matches.
```

So, isn't it possible to use observable fields on the `View` side of two-way databinding like it's possible on the `ViewModel`? The reason I want to use observable fields instead of static `BindingAdapter`s is that my `View` has some more complex logic/state than I can handle in the `BindingAdapter` (well, from the static `BindingAdapter` I could just call through to `myViewInstance.myValue`, but somehow that feels  wrong to me)

**Update**

I built a minimum (not) working example, [available on Github](https://github.com/wondering639/stack-view-observable)
By default it uses one-way binding, which works fine. Changing

```
app:myValue="@{viewModel.realValue}"
```

to

```
app:myValue="@={viewModel.realValue}"
```

in `activity_main.xml` will lead to not very informative compilation errors. Use `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`to get a long output which includes

```
ERROR: Cannot find a getter for 
<com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView app:myValue> 
that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'
```

Can anyone have a look at this and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you implementing Observable in your view?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to to

Comment: Just simply implement Observable interface in your view and you will be able to use @Bindable

Comment: That's actually what I did! but it simply does not find the getter, even worse, the error message about missing a getter with a String parameter is quite confusing for me and I don't understand it. Did you ever implement Observable on a View?

Comment: Yes, I did implement Observable in View without any issue. Can you please change the field variable to myValue in your getter and setter and check if it works?

Comment: I changed it in the getter, but the issue remains. changing in the setter isn't possible, than it won't create a backing field. anyway, I created a minimum (not) working example available on Github. Please see my update of my question for more details and a link to the Github repository. Maybe you can have a look at it / try yourself? :-)

Comment: Try this annotation on variable instead! `@get:Bindable` & see if it works

Comment: What is the need of two bindings in the textview? text value will not get changed from the view then why to use two-way binding?

Comment: @JeelVankhede Doesn't help unfortunately ):

Comment: @MohitDholakia AutoCompleteTextView is used in Material Componenets for ExposedD Dropdown menu (like a Spinner)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf from what I understood you want to update the string value from livedata but you also want to keep the string inside your CustomView itself. You are defining your namespace i.e app:myValue and expecting 2-way databinding too work without using BindingAdapter annotation

Comment: that's right, I would expect it to find getter/setter using naming convention. that's also what the documentation claims at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#automatic-setting

Answer (score 1):

> When using Android two-way databinding, do I have to use static BindingAdapters on the View or is it somehow possible to simply use observable instance fields?

I think it's pretty much possible for you to do that with the Observable instance fields. However **if** this logic is being reused somewhere else as well, I would personally prefer to use `BindingAdapters`.

In your Observable class, modify your code to this:

```
@get:Bindable
var myValue: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value 
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myValue) // my View implements the Observable interface
    }
```

---

I checked out your repo and realized that you are using MutableLiveData now, so you don't need the above code in that case. I also couldn't find any BindingAdapter there. Make sure your code BindingAdapter looks somewhat like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("myValue")
@JvmStatic
fun TextView.setMyValue(realValue: String) {
    val finalValue : String = realValue.dataManipulation() // Do your data manipulation here
    setText(finalValue) // Make sure it's a string
}
```

And then finally your TextView in XML should look like this:

```
<com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView
    ...
    app:myValue="@{viewModel.realValue}"
    ... />
```

Let me know if this worked.

---

---

**EDIT**

So what we are looking for is basically Bindable variables in BaseObservable class. Let's focus on three things: your XML, your activity/fragment and your BindingModel class.

Your BindingModel class basically extends your BaseObservable class.

```
class BindingModel: BaseObservable(){
    @get:Bindable
    var myValue: String = ""
        set(value) {
            var finalValue = manipulateData(value) //Write your logic here
            field = finalValue
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myValue) // my View implements the Observable interface
    }
...
}
```

In your Activity/Fragment, create a variable of type `BindingModel`. Observe your LiveData and update the variable.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
val model = BindingModel()
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this // Specify the current activity as the lifecycle owner.
    binding.model = model
    viewModel.realValue.observe(this, Observer {
        model.myValue = it
    })
} // End of onCreate()
...
} // End of Activity code
```

Moving on to your XML, you need to declare the `model` data binding variable there.

```
...
<data>
...
<variable
    name="model" //Make sure the name is same
    type="com.example.test.<path-to-your-file>.BindingModel" />
</data>
...
<com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView
...
android:text="@{model.realValue}" //Don't forget this
... />
```

And voila! It should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, but I know it works with adapters. What I am wonderig about is, why it does not work WITHOUT an adapter?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I have editted my answer. I think it should work for you